# Linked server errror: Cannot get the current row value of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL SERVER:

```
select *
    from ADRESSEN
     where Transferred is NOT null
     and NR_ID not in (Select NR_ID from openquery(PROD, 'Select * from TABELLEN.NUMMERN'))
```

When I execute this query I get this error:

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "PROD" returned message "".
Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 12
Cannot get the current row value of column "[OraOLEDB.Oracle].NR_ID" from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "PROD".
```

But when I comment one of the condition in `WHERE` and I execute it, the query works:

```
select *
    from ADRESSEN
     where Transferred is NOT null
```

It works! And this too:

```
select *
    from ADRESSEN
     where 
          NR_ID not in (Select NR_ID from openquery(PROD, 'Select * from TABELLEN.NUMMERN'))
```